# 2 identical elements returned in array, after mysql query, why?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Ive made a mysql query using PDO like this

```
$timestamp_query = "SELECT timestamp FROM change_me;";

foreach ($conn->query($timestamp_query) as $times ) {
    print_r($times); 
    echo "<br>";
 }
```

But this is giving me back a set of arrays like this

```
Array ( [timestamp] => 2013-05-24 17:55:04 [0] => 2013-05-24 17:55:04 )
Array ( [timestamp] => 2013-05-24 18:00:05 [0] => 2013-05-24 18:00:05 )
Array ( [timestamp] => 2013-05-24 18:05:04 [0] => 2013-05-24 18:05:04 )
```

Why is this giving me 2 identical elements in each array, as opposed to just one ?

Comment: I'm far from a PDO expert, but I think `$times` is a *row*, and you need to go after `$times[0]` or `$times['timestamp']` to get the value.

Comment: As your `$conn->query($timestamp_query)` is an associative array, you can access the values returned with either set keys or numeric keys. I believe that is what you are seeing, with `print_r()` showing you both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns an associative array to you so you can reference the results by either field name or index.

E.g. `$times['timestamp']` or `$times[0]`

Answer (score 5):

You need to change your fetch mode from PDO::FETCH_BOTH to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

```
foreach ($conn->query($timestamp_query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $times )
```

This will change it so that it only returns the data as an associative array.

Alternatively if you want only an indexed array you can use PDO::FETCH_ARRAY or for an object use PDO::FETCH_OBJECT.

More information can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)